# How can I pass data back to a parent component in VueJS?

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, vue-component

I have a component called `programme`, which has another component called `question` within it.

Within `question` I have a timer component (https://github.com/xkeshi/vue-countdown), which counts down and then fires an event when it hits zero.

I need to listen to this event within the `programme` component.  How can I do this?

To give a little context, `programme` plays a number of videos and then asks the user a question, the user has *n* seconds to answer and if they are unable to do so then the previous video plays.  This logic happens in `programme`, hence why I need the event to be accessible in `programme`.

For reference, here is the countdown timer:

```
<countdown :time="timerAmount" v-show="isTimed" v-on:countdownend="onCountdownEnd">
    <template slot-scope="props">{{ props.minutes }}:{{ props.seconds }}</template>
</countdown>
```

Comment: by using global event bus https://alligator.io/vuejs/global-event-bus/

Comment: Yes I would recommend using event bus!

Comment: I achieved this in the end by using a global Event Bus: https://alligator.io/vuejs/global-event-bus/

Answer (score 1):

There is a way to do this if you didn't want to implement an event bus as suggested above (which I probably would). Children can `$emit` events that can be heard by direct parents and no more. So if i'm understanding you correctly, and you have the following component structure,

```
<programme v-on:expired="setNewQuestion">
  <question v-on:expired="handleExpired">
     <countdown v-on:oncountdownend="onCountdownEnd" />
  </question>
</programme>
```

a way to do what your asking is to emit an event called `expired` in your `onCountdownEnd` function within the `<countdown />` component, as below

```
// in the <countdown> component
methods: {
  onCountdownEnd(somedata) {
    this.$emit("expired", somedata)
  }
}
```

and then in it's parent component, `question`, you would have a listener waiting for the event you've emitted called `expired`, and have it also `$emit` an event to it's parent, as below

```
// in the <question> component
methods: {
  handleExpired(somedata) {
    this.$emit("expired", somedata)
  }
}
```

and finally in the upper parent `programme` you'd also have a listener for an event, which i've again called `expired` above, that runs a function when it's triggered, as below

```
// in the <programme> component
methods: {
  setNewQuestion(somedata) {
    // do something with the data or tick over to new question etc
  }
}
```

I hope that helps and has made sense. Feel free to message if you have any questions!

Answer (score 0):

It would be easier to understand if you provided the minimum code for your application and components.

If I understand it correctly then you need to add onCountdownEnd method to your parent component, it can be done like this:

```
<script>
  methods: {
    onCountdownEnd (data) {
      // do something
    }
  }
</script>
```

I recommend to use Vuex to store state of your application, it will save you from a headache.